# How to point child domain to specific port on localhost in windows server 2008 VPS?

Tags: nginx, dns, windows-server-2008, vps

I have a `VPS` which is running `Windows server 2008 datacenter` with one Static IP address.

I can access from Internet to my web services by specific port e.g `mydomain.com:3000/api` and `mydomain.com:4000/api`. I want to change this web services access address into sub domain method (child) like  `App1WS.mydomain.com/api` and `App2WS.mydomain.com/api`

I add this line to `host` file

```
127.0.0.1      mobileapp.myrealdomain.com
```

Then in nginx, I add these lines at the end

```
 server {
        listen       80;
        #root html;
        root c:/apps/web;
        server_name  mobileapp.myrealdomain.com;
       location / {
           proxy_pass  "http://127.0.0.1:3000";
        }
}
```

Then I started my loopback project which is accessible via:

```
C:\apps\mobileapp>node .
Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000
Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer
```

Then I've add Alias(CNMAE) record to DNS:

```
alias name: mobileapp
FQDN: mobileapp.myrealdomain.com
FQDN for target host: 127.0.0.1:3000.
```

From other location on Internet  `myrealdomain.com` loads homepage but still `mobileapp.myrealdomain.com` showing

```
server DNS address could not be found.
```

In VPS  `mobileapp.myrealdomain.com` works properly and loads server up time

```
{"started":"2017-09-23T10:29:30.626Z","uptime":48.709}
```

**update:**

result of testing:

[image]

[image]

Comment: DNS (mostly) doesn't handle ports, so if your api was reachable using `mydomain.com:3000/api`, remove the `CNAME` you added and use this one: `mobileapp.myrealdomain.com CNAME myrealdomain.com`. Nginx will do the proxying to the correct port.

Comment: Dear @dusan-bajic I did but nothing is changed, I've add: `alias name: mobileapp
FQDN: mobileapp.myrealdomain.com
FQDN for target host: myrealdomain.com` I also made a child and add cname but still the same.

Comment: If you go to https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/ and test `A` records `mobileapp.myrealdomain.com` and `myrealdomain.com`, do they resolve to the same IP address?

Comment: I add photo of A and CNAME to the main post.

Comment: DNS propogation takes time. Please try `ping mobileapp.myrealdomain.com` from the machine where it doesn't work. When the ping shows you the ip then only you can test. DNS updates can take anywhere between 30mins to 2 days also depending on different conditions. So if you are in a hurry to test if the server works fine or not. Then on the machine you are testing make a host entry `51.XXX.104.172 mobileapp.myrealdomain.com` and then test. If it works then that means you are just waiting for DNS changes to propogate

Comment: Dear@TarunLalwani  and @DusanBajic I don't know what was wrong yesterday. but the same rule with CNMAE that you already told me, today works fine. I tried several subdomains for other web services and they start right after DNS and nginx restarted. Thank you so much.